# What concrete meaning of the input of Transformer Decoder

Tags: transformer-model

When I design my own network, there are an encoder and decoder.

I want to use Transformer Decoder as my model's decoder.

I implement this through followed code

```
self.layer = nn.TransformerDecoderLayer(d_model=768, nhead=4)
self.decoder = nn.TransformerDecoder(decoder_layer=self.layer,
                                         num_layers=2)
```

But I found there are two required inputs: 'tgt' and 'memory'.

I do not know what concrete meaning about these two parameters enven after I queried the official manual.
I would appreciate if anyone can explain it, and give a concrete example.